# How to handle django model forms error in view.py file?

Tags: python, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

This is my forms.py file.We can validate form data from the clean method in forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


    class ContactForm(forms.Form):
        # Everything as before.
        ...
    
        def clean_recipients(self):
            data = self.cleaned_data['recipients']
            if "fred@example.com" not in data:
                raise ValidationError("You have forgotten about Fred!")
    
            # Always return a value to use as the new cleaned data, even if
            # this method didn't change it.
```

But i want to validate some data in view.py.Can we do that ? In view.py file

```
class Test(View) :
    def get(self,request):
      #Get logic 
   def post(self,request):
      form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
      if form.is_valid():
          num = form.cleaned_data['num']
          
          if '123' in num:
               form.add_error('num','Not valid')
          else:
               form.save()
              
      return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})
```

What is way to handle forms error in view.py not in forms.py

Comment: You can use messages, or pass the form error as context to your template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using messages

1. views.py

   ```
   from django.contrib import messages
   class Test(View) :
       def post(self,request):
           form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
           if form.is_valid():
               num = form.cleaned_data['num']

               if '123' in num:
                   messages.error(request, 'Not valid')
               else:
                   form.save()

           return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form})
   ```
2. templates

   ```
   {% if messages %}
       {% for message in messages %}
           <p>{{ message }}</p>
       {% endfor %}
   {% endif %}
   ```

Another way is to pass error as context

1. Views.py

   ```
   from django.contrib import messages
   class Test(View) :
       def post(self,request):
           form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
           if form.is_valid():
               num = form.cleaned_data['num']

               if '123' in num:
                   num = 'Not Valid'
               else:
                   form.save()

           return render(request,self.template_name,{'form':form,'num':num})
   ```
2. And then use the variable inside templates

   ```
   {{num}}
   ```